# Visual Studio builds njsproj Node.js project even though there are no changes since last build

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, msbuild

I've added a *Blank Node.js Web Application* project to my solution. It is a *.njsproj the among of other C# *.csproj projects.

The project works fine. Visual Studio build runs `npm run build` according the package.json. There is only one thing bothering me. The *.njsproj is built everytime I build the solution.

Visual Studio can recognize when there is **no change** in the C# *.csproj projects and skips them saying they are up-to-date:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 29 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, this does not work for the *.njsproj. The `npm run build` (raised from AfterCompile target in Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets) is executed every single time even though there is absolutely no change in any of the solution projects or files at all.

Is Visual Studio even able to track changes of Node.js project to skip the build or there is no chance to make it work similar to the C# projects?

All the Node.js project files have Build Action set to None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is impossible. This is related to the VS IDE's internal build mechanism for Node JS projects of this type. And it is designed by that.

And I should tell you that the up-to-date check is a feature for **VS IDE**. You can try the **VS IDE Build** and **MSBuild command line build** `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build` with the c# project, and you will find that:

**IDE build** will not execute any msbuild system target, and it detects that it should not build again since there is no changes to minimize the workload of MSBuild.

**However**, when you use msbuild command line, no matter there is no changes, it still invokes the many system default targets which will make a burden with a large solution.

**So** the `up-to-date` is a feature for VS IDE which will helps reduce the burden of msbuild.

**We** could only modify target one by one to skip by [inputs, outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019). But this is meaningless since `up-to-date` is a new detection mechanism which is not dependent on MSBuild and Targets. There is no msbuild function to get the `up-to-date` under node js projects.

**That** is an internal mechanism We cannot handle that area, you need to contact the Microsoft product team by VS IDE menu-->**Help**-->**Send Feedback**-->**Report a problem** or [that](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I reported that to MS like you suggested.

Comment: The MS ticket is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Up-to-date-IDE-build-skipping-feature-is/1384663